# Is it safe (in matter of uniqueness) to use UUID to generate a unique identifier for specific string?

Tags: java, hash, uuid, sha256

```
String myText;
UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes((myText).getBytes()).toString();
```

I am using above code to generate a representative for specific texts.
For example 'Moien' should **always** be represeted with "e9cad067-56f3-3ea9-98d2-26e25778c48f", not any changes like project rebuild should be able to change that UUID.

The reason why I'm doing this is so that I don't want those specific texts to be readable(understandable) to human.

Note: I don't need the ability to regenerate the main text (e.g "Moien") after hashing .

I have an alternative way too :

```
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] hash = digest.digest((matcher.group(1)).getBytes("UTF-8"));
            String a = Base64.encode(hash);
```

Which od you think is better for my problem?

Comment: "is that i don't want those specific texts to be readable(understandable) to human. " - why?  this worries me since it could mean you are using *encoding* instead of *encryption*

Comment: The former uses `MD5` instead of `SHA-256` but the result is equivalent: it provides a value from a finite set for an (practically) infinite source set, trying to make clashes unlikely but not impossible. In other words, it is not “safe (in matter of uniqueness)” as your question title asks. If you want to exclude clashes entirely, hashing is not the right tool.

Comment: He's not looking for encoding but hashing.

Comment: @dkatzel e.g i need to check if A equals B. but if not, I dont want B to know what is the actuall value of A and vise versa. so i transform A and B with some one-way hashing to an string and then check if the hashed strings are equal or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes` appears to basically just be MD5 hashing, with the result being represented as a UUID.

It feels clearer to me to use a base64-encoded hash explicitly, partly as you can then control which hash gets used - which could be relevant if collisions pose any sort of security risk. (SHA-256 is likely a better option than MD5 for exactly that reason.) The string will be longer from SHA-256 of course, but hopefully that's not a problem.

Note that in *either* case, I'd convert the string to text using a fixed encoding via [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html). Don't use the platform default (as per your first snippet) and prefer `StandardCharsets` over magic string values (as per your second snippet).